# How to make django load static files from a built react project

Tags: reactjs, django, web, static, react-fullstack

This is my project structure, I have already finished both the backend and frontend in Django and React. To host my project, I built React and loaded 'index.html' as a template, while the built CSS and JS are used as static files.

backend
----backend
----base
----frontend
----build
----static
----css
----js
----media
index.html
// other files like favicons and JSON
----node_modules
----public
----src
----staticfiles
----db.sqlite3
-----manage.py

Here is my `settings.py` to handle static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/static/css',
    BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/static/js',
    BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/static/media',
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

When I turn DEBUG = True, the site runs on port 8000, but the images need to be re-uploaded to the database because it can't find those images after I built the React project. When I turn DEBUG = False, I get the following error in the console:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/main.1d564988.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

The same problem occurs for the CSS files. I tried hosting the site, but I can't load the static files.